# How to add a port from a server into connection string with linked services on Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, connection-string, azure-synapse-analytics

I am working on a project and need to connect to a server in Azure Synapse Analytics. I have successfully achieved this using the Integration Runtime. Now, I need to connect to a database on this server and I'm using linked services. I input all the parameters, including the password stored in Azure Key Vault. I am following a pattern provided by Microsoft for the connection string. However, I couldn't find any information online about how to include the port used by the database server. How can I pass this parameter in JSON or in the Parameters tab or through Additional connection properties?

`{ "name": "SqlServerLinkedService", "properties": { "type": "SqlServer", "typeProperties": { "connectionString": "Data Source=<servername>\\<instance name if using named instance>;Initial Catalog=<databasename>;Integrated Security=False;User ID=<username>;", "password": {  "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",  "store": {  "referenceName": "<Azure Key Vault linked service name>",  "type": "LinkedServiceReference"  },  "secretName": "<secretName>"  } }, "connectVia": { "referenceName": "<name of Integration Runtime>", "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference" } } }`

[image: Image about connection on Linked Services]

I searched on YouTube and ChatGPT, but I couldn't find any solution. I need to add this port somewhere in the JSON or in the connection parameters.

Comment: In connection strings you'd usually specify it in the `Data Source`/`Server` property. So instead of `Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName;` have you tried `Data Source=ServerName,PortNumber;`? (Note the use of comma `,` to delimit the server name and port number.)

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/using-a-non-standard-port/

Comment: I tried this one, but it didn't work. Is there another way?

Comment: "Didn't work" doesn't mean anything. Please post the error.